# Perché '17 si riferisce ancora al 1917 e non al 2017?

Tags: word-usage

Considerando che abbiamo ampiamente  superato l'anno 2009, perché continuiamo a dire "duemiladiciassette", ecc., invece di usare solo le ultime due cifre?

Perché quando diciamo "nel diciassette" intendiamo ancora il 1917?

Comment: Forse semplicemente “perché lo si dice da tanto tempo” e quindi in un certo senso ormai ha attecchito? I più grandi di età fra noi ancora esitano fra '800 e '900 quando sentono dire “il secolo scorso”... D'altro canto il “Quarantotto” è per antonomasia quello dell'800, e lo “spirito dell'Ottantanove” in certi contesti si riferisce alla Rivoluzione francese (in altri, alla caduta dei muri dell'Europa dell'est).

Comment: (Ci tengo comunque a dire che non ho dato io il voto negativo, e chiederei a chi l'ha dato di lasciare anche un commento possibilmente costruttivo.)

Comment: @CarLaTex downvote a causa di click a cavolo. Me ne sono accorto ora. Succede, ogni tanto (almeno a me).

Comment: Infatti, e soprattutto a me che ho badili al posto delle mani :))

Comment: Forse la spinta ad abbreviare è proporzionale al guadagno che ne deriva. Millenovecento sono sei sillabe, duemila solo tre. La frase "Nel millenovecentodiciannove" fa un endecasillabo da sola! Forse duemiladiciassette è ancora una parola pronunciabile senza troppo sforzo.

Comment: @CasaMich Mi sembra un'ottima spiegazione!

Comment: Credo che @DaG  abbia ragione, credo sia solo una questione di abitudine! Quando aumenteranno le persone nate dopo il 2000 questo non succederà più!

Comment: @Filippo1980 Mi sa di sì, è solo questione di tempo :)

Comment: [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1849/)

Comment: @DenisNardin Essendo stata adolescente negli anni '80, sono perfettamente d'accordo :):):)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nei numerali che indicano un anno** (sia per *date vicine nel tempo* o *legate all’esperienza di chi parla* – come una data di nascita – sia *celebri* in modo antonomastico – per *date storiche*), **possono essere soppresse le prime due cifre**, sostituite da un segno di apostrofo:

- *Io sono del ’72, e mia sorella del ’75*
- *I ragazzi del ’99*
- *La rivoluzione del ’17*

Tuttavia **non esiste una regola precisa** in tal senso. L'abbreviazione della data è possibile se sono note le due cifre precedenti soggette all'aferesi di cui si ha traccia nell'apostofo.

Per cui, se si sta parlando dei moti del '48 è noto a tutti che si parla del 1848, altrimenti per consuetudine si intenderà il 1948. Tuttavia **difficilmente**, a parte alcune date celebri, si sentirà dire "*la rivoluzione francese del '89*" o "*la scoperta dell'America del '92*".

La **consuetudine** è comunque quella di avere l'aferesi per le date del secolo scorso (1900), con la caduta di *millenovecento*. Non si ha tale abbreviazione per tutte le rimanenti date (a meno appunto di date celebri). *Presumibilmente i nostri pronipoti cambieranno tale consuetudine* e dicendo *nel '17* intenderanno l'anno 2017 e non il 1917.

Con riferimento al secolo scorso, da analoghe locuz. russe, passate in francese e poi in altre lingue, gli a. venti, gli a. quaranta, e sim., per indicare il periodo che va approssimativamente dal 1920 al 1929, dal 1940 al 1949, ecc., in rapporto a fatti caratteristici o particolari: i ruggenti a. venti (traduz. dell’ingl. the roaring twenties: v. ruggente); il cinema degli a. trenta; la Germania degli a. cinquanta, ecc. (spesso con iniziale maiuscola: gli a. Venti, gli a. Trenta; o, meno spesso, col numerale: gli a. ’20, ’30, ecc.).

L’uso del numerale cardinale è dedicato soltanto all’indicazione dei secoli che coprono l’arco temporale dal 1001 al 2000 d.C. Avremo pertanto il nome del secolo, scritto con l’iniziale maiuscola e preceduto dall’articolo determinativo: il Cento (di uso molto raro), il Duecento, il Trecento, il Quattrocento, il Cinquecento, il Seicento, il Settecento, l’Ottocento e il Novecento (che va dal 1901 al 2000; si noti, invece, che gli anni Venti vanno dal 1920 al 1929, gli anni Trenta dal 1930 al 1939, ecc.). La trascrizione in cifre arabe, come quella in lettere, omette l’indicazione del migliaio, segnalato però da un apostrofo: ’200, ’300, ’400, ’500, ’600, ’700, ’800 e ’900. Il numerale con il migliaio, infatti, indicherebbe non l’intero secolo, ma l’anno preciso: così il 1200 è l’anno dal 1° gennaio al 31 dicembre 1200; ma va aggiunto che spesso l’anno è usato anche, impropriamente, come punto di riferimento per indicare un secolo; per es., in Italia la scrittura apparve nel 700 a.C. [ovvero nell’VIII sec. a.C.]; l’Italia del 1600, ecc.

Notiamo inoltre che molte Case Editrici, nelle loro regole editoriali, vietano le notazioni con apostrofo a meno di casi particolari e prescrivono ad esempio

- Le date vanno sempre scritte per esteso: *nel 1963* [non nel ’63];
- Le date doppie vanno abbreviate sostituendo con il trattino il millennio e il secolo della seconda: 2005-07 [mai 2005-'07]
- I secoli, i decenni e gli anni di particolare rilevanza storica si scrivono in lettere con l'iniziale maiuscola: *il Seicent*o [non il ’600], *gli anni Venti* [non gli anni ’20], *il Sessantotto* [non il ’68]

Anche qui, non sono regole scolpite nella pietra ma legate a scelte editoriali.